# How to use a scheduler(cron) container to execute commands in other containers

Tags: docker, cron, containers, scheduler, job-scheduling

I've spent a fair amount of time researching and I've not found a solution to my problem that I'm comfortable with. My app is working in a dockerized environment:

1. one container for the **database**;
2. one or more containers for the **APP itself**. Each container holds a **specific version** of the APP.

It's a multi-tenant application, so **each client (or tenant) may be related to only one version at a time** (migration should be handle per client, but that's not relevant).

The problem is I would like to have another container to handle scheduling jobs, like sending e-mails, processing some data, etc. The scheduler would then execute commands in app's containers. Projects like [Ofelia](https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia) offer a great promise but I would have to know the container to execute the command ahead of time. That's not possible because I need to go to the database container to discover which version the client is in, to figure it out what container the command should be executed in.

Is there a tool to help me here? Should I change the structure somehow? Any tips would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is you want to get the APP's version info in the database container before scheduling jobs,right?
I think this is relate to the business， not the dockerized environment,you may have ways to slove the problem:

1. Check the network ,make sure the network of the container can connect to each other
2. I think the database should support RPC function,you can use it to get the version data
3. You can use some RPC supported tools,like SSH

Comment: Hey charlie, actually I have ways to get the container ID, they will be registered in the database as well. What I'm struggling with is how to run that command inside another container. I was told me that sharing the docker host socket should be avoided, so it takes the ```docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID COMMAD``` possibility.